# I can't import classes to a module from a different module in my project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, cucumber

I have a groovy gradle project in IntelliJ with a bunch of modules.
One of those I call QA and is just cucumber functional tests.
I am trying to import a helper class which is present in a different module (in the test code) but I can't seem to be able  to do it.

The other module is called COMMON-UTILS.

In the gradle settings file of QA I added the lines to unclude the project

```
include ':COMMON-UTILS'
project(':COMMON-UTILS').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../common-util')
```

and in the build gradle file I included in the dependencies the lines

```
compile project(':COMMON-UTILS')
testCompile project(path: ':COMMON-UTILS', configuration: 'tests')
```

I can't seem to get it to work. 
The problem is this is a project I came later on and I am not really knowledgeable on gradle and cucumber and classpaths so I think I might be missing something and I don't understand everything in the gradle build file.

For IntelliJ to be able to auto complete classes it has to be able to know where to look at right? Do I have to add something on the classpath on the module?
If I go to the dependencies of the module I can see the COMMON-UTILS there in the list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that stuff on the class path isn't exposed to other modules.

I would consider moving the helper class to the production code in the project you are depending on and see if that makes any difference.

If it makes a difference, you need to start thinking on how you should do to share this helper class. But that is hopefully easier when you can use it from the places you need it. A common module could be one option to consider.